# What is the method for obtaining lagrangians from metrics?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

In general given a line element $ds^2=g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ how does one obtain the Lagrangian.

My lecturer said that we should be able to just read off the Lagrangian from the metric but I have seen 3 formulas for obtaining it

$L=g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$  For flat Euclidean space

$L=\tfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ For curved space

$L=-g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ for Minkowski space-time.

I see no rhyme nor reason to choosing these, certainly the problem seems more complicated then just reading the Lagrangian from the metric, but no method was given in class .

Could anyone please explain to me how we obtain Lagrangians for given metrics ?

Comment: The Lagrangian for what, though?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić The lagrangian of the field itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lagrangian is always $\mathcal{L}=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$. Multiplying the Lagrangian by a constant does not change the physics and is only done to simplify the algebraic expression.